# Code for hooking popup to update column values in gwt-incumbator pagging scroll table

Tags: gwt

Hie

the demo shows you can click on any column and update the value.

can someone share the code how it has been implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi You can use GwtExt or SmartGWT Editable grid and it also gives components for implementing Paging in it.

link to editable grid in GwtExt is [here](http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo/#editableGrid)

You can also find paging that is also local and remote both

Comment: You can use SmartGWT which is much better.